# pagination in form php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i have this code :

`<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
body {
background-image: url(../images/paper_03.png);
}
form {
background-image: url(../images/paper_02.png);
}
</style>
</head>
<?php

require("../function.php");
// echo sizeof($_SESSION['liste']);



?>
<body >
<form name="log"  method="post"  style="position: absolute; top:50px; left: 320px; width: 600px; height: 100%;" >

                        <table BORDER=2 style="position: relative; top:15px; left: 3px;" >
                        <TR> 
                         <TH style="width:100px"><font color="blue">Date</font></TH> 
                         <TH style="width:400px"><font color="blue">Location</font></TH> 
                          <TH style="width:400px"><font color="blue">Job Title</font></TH> 
                         <TH style="width:300px"><font color="blue">Company</font></TH> 
                        </TR>
                        <?php
                        session_start();
                        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_SESSION['liste']);$i++){
                        ?>
                        <TR>
                        <td ><center><label><?php echo $_SESSION['liste'][$i]['date']; ?></label></center></td> 
                         <td ><label><?php echo $_SESSION['liste'][$i]['region'].','.$_SESSION['liste'][$i]['city'].','.$_SESSION['liste'][$i]['state']; ?></label></td> 
                         <td ><center><label><?php echo $_SESSION['liste'][$i]['title']; ?></label></center></td> 
                         <td ><center><label><?php echo $_SESSION['liste'][$i]['comapany_name']; ?></label></center></td> 
                        </TR>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </table>


</form>

</body>
</html>`

i have a form i want that every 10 results be displayed togother ie add the pagination to my form with two icons ( next, previous ).

- can i do this only with php?
- do i need ajax in this work?

Comment: Yes you can do with php alone but then for every "next" click your page will load again with next page's values. But if you do it with ajax then you can just reload the relevant part. But if you are learning then better to go the php way first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass a $liststart value in as a parameter to your code (get it with $liststart = $_REQUEST['liststart']).
2. Then adjust your loop to loop from $liststart to $liststart+10.
3. Make a button that onClick, goes to your code above with the new $liststart value.  for example for the 'next' button on the first page, use echo "' onClick='location.href=\"yourcodeabove.php?liststart=".$liststart+10."\";'>";

or if you prefer, you could do it without javascript by making the next and prev buttons their own forms.  like this:

```
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="yourcodeabove.php?liststart="<?php $liststart+10 ?>">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="next->">
</FORM>
```

close out your other form first (which doesn't look like it needs to be a form actually... could be a *div* just as well).  forms usually have 'actions' and are submitted with buttons but since you'll have 2 buttons (next and prev) each could be their own form with either the javascript onClick or the form method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql this should work:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT $page, 10");
```

And do some work with $query variable, your links should be something like this:

```
<a href="/somefile.php?page=<?= $current_page + 1;?>">Next</a>
```